# If $a | ( b + c )$ and $a | ( b - c )$, then $a | b$ and $a |c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Have to prove - If $a | (b+c) $ and $a | (b-c) $, then $a | b $ and $a | c $
Don't really know, which approach to take. Thought maybe to break this statement on parts, and prove:

1. If $a | (b+c) $, then $a | b $ and $a | c $
2. If $a | (b-c) $, then $a | b $ and $a | c $
   But don't know if it is going to be valid. Can someone suggest which approach to take?

Comment: It isn't true.  Take $(a,b,c)=(2,3,1)$ for example.

Comment: But does the wrong example proves, that the statement is wrong in every case? Excuse me, I'm asking genuinely, not that fluent. I thought the idea, is to prove it formally

Comment: If a divides 2 numbers, it must also divide their difference and sum, try and build onto that

Comment: If $a$ is odd the claim is true, otherwise it's false in general, as per the counterexample given by lulu.

Comment: The wrong example shows that the statement "For every $a,b,c$, if $a|b+c$ and $a|b-c$, then $a|b$ and $a|c$" is false.

Comment: Another set of examples is to let $c = b$ and $a=2b$.

Comment: See the linked dupe a the *correct* statement and methods of proof for such problems, e.g. the methods there derive $\,a\mid 2b,2c\,$ so $\,a\mid (2b,2c) = 2(b,c)\ \ $

Comment: @BrunoB But how to prove, that when a is odd the claim is true. How did you see that? Would it be valid, to make an assumption from the beginning : Let's suppose a is odd, then ...

Comment: If you miscopied the problem then let me know the correct statement so we can make the dupe links more precise (most all problems of this sort are by now dupes).

Comment: Hopefully you have at least understood why $a$ divides $2b$ and $2c$ (with Bill's link or with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/531205/1104384)). Then, the reason why $a$ odd makes the claim true is simply because if $a$ divides $2b$, then we have $ka = 2b$, but since $a$ is odd, $k$ as to be even, otherwise the odd number $ka$ would be equal to the even number $2b$, thus $k = 2k'$. Therefore $2k'a = 2b$, and so $k'a = b$, hence $a$ divides $b$, and then it's the same for $c$. (Might probably count as an answer of sorts but the question is closed so it'll be a comment instead)

Comment: @BrunoB What i've done was - _a | ( b + c)_ and _a | ( b - c )_, then _b + c = am_, and _b - c = an_ . So _b = am - c_ and _b=an + c_ ; _am - c = an + c_ , _a ( m - n ) = 2c_ ; _ap = 2c_, where p is an integer and equals to ( m - n ). That's what you've said in the first part of the comment. What i don't get, is the calm **but since a is odd, k as to be even**. Why the a is odd. Because a can be even also. Unless, at the beginning of the proof, this claim is set. That a is odd. However, i don't understand, why is it valid to simply tell, that a is odd.

Comment: While i don't show, that this claim doesn't hold for a to be even. However, in the expression _ap = 2c_, a can be even, and p can be odd. Or both to be even. 
Sorry for me being stubborn, seems i'm lacking knowledge, and don't understand.

Comment: I decided to set $a$ odd because that way the claim is true AND because there already are counterexamples provided for the general claim when $a$ wasn't of fixed parity. To prove your general claim false, it is not necessary to prove that *for all* $(a,b,c)$ with $a$ even the claim doesn't hold, because it'll still hold for some of those triplets, instead it suffices to only check that *one* such triplet makes the claim false.